# Getting a HTTP 500 upon opening the Experience Editor in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

On a long running site a certain user always gets an HTTP 500 when opening the Experience Editor in Sitecore 8.1. This also persists if I create a new user with the same roles, leading me to believe that it is something in the roles. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out what's going on. The browser just gives me an HTTP 500 error, and the log contains barely any information. Is there anyone with any ideas that could solve this?

The log message says:

```
4040 14:52:58 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.RenderingLayoutAreaResolveStrategy.GetLayoutAreaValue(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ChainedAreaResolveStrategy.Resolve(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ResolveArea.ResolveAreaInfo(RenderRenderingArgs args, IRouteData routeData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ResolveArea.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

The Sitecore roles this user has are:

- sitecore\Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Users
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Social Authoring
- sitecore\Analytics Testing
- sitecore\Analytics Personalization
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing
- sitecore\Designer
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Security
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing

Besides this there are about 110 other roles that we have defined internally which restrict access to certain parts of the tree under `Content`, and one role that denies all access to `Layout`, 'Social', 'System' and 'Templates`.

Comment: Can you please share the list of roles assigned to these users? Also when you say "Certain user", is there any user working fine with these roles?

Comment: I've updated my question @AmitabhVyas. There are no other users that work with all of these roles, but it used to work. The customer started complaining a couple of weeks ago, unfortunately that doesn't match any deployment or changes from our end.

Comment: We get the same error on both CM (EE) and CD (as visitor) servers when trying to access a specific page, using the same template as other pages, that work. Removing all components from the page makes no difference, but when I moved it from one location ion the tree to another it started to work.